# I am facing this error "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token):" while prase the url data using minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am facing this error `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0`  while parse data from url using minidom. Anyone can help me for this ?

Here is my code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib2
url= 'http://www.awgp.org/about_us'
openurl=urllib2.urlopen(url)
doc=minidom.parse("about_us.xml")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test3.py", line 11, in <module>
doc=minidom.parse("about_us.xml")
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
return expatbuilder.parse(file)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 924, in parse
result = builder.parseFile(fp)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 211, in parseFile
parser.Parse("", True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

Comment: Looks like your "about_us.xml" file is empty. Have you written anything into it? You've called urlopen but you have not shown where you actually read from it and neither have you shown where you write to your "about_us.xml" file.

Comment: does your about_us.xml file is well formatted ?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I am doing doc=minidom.parse(openurl). But still it shows me same error.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I am not able to understand what the error actually means ? So if you have idea then can you please explain it here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
parser.Parse("", True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

The above from your traceback indicates to me that your "about_us.xml" file is empty.
You have `openurl` but you have not shown that you've ever called `openurl.read()` to actually get at the data.
Nor have you shown where or how you've written said data to your "about_us.xml" file.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib2
url= 'http://www.awgp.org/about_us'
openurl=urllib2.urlopen(url)
doc=minidom.parse(openurl)
print doc
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    doc=minidom.parse(openurl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 51, column 81
```

which indicates that the page you are trying to parse as XML is not well-formed. Try using [beautiful soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) instead which, from memory, is very forgiving.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url= 'http://www.awgp.org/about_us'
openurl=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(openurl.read())
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
  print (a.text, a.get('href'))
```

BTW, you'll need ver 3 of Beautiful Soup since you're still on python 2.7

Comment: BTW, huge thanks to https://repl.it/languages/python for the online python interpreter.